# Using a for loop to categorize data

Tags: r

I am trying to split a data set by state so I will end up with 8 different smaller datasets. I could do this manually but I also want to be able to apply this to variables with more than 8 categories. my `for` loop is:

```r
States <- list("Qld","NSW","Tas","SA","Vic","NT","WA","ACT")
for (x in States){
  x = data
  x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA)
  x <- na.omit(x)
  View(x)
}
```

and the error message i get is:

> Warning messages:
> 1: In x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA) :
> Coercing LHS to a list
> 2: In x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA) :
> Coercing LHS to a list
> 3: In x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA) :
> Coercing LHS to a list
> 4: In x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA) :
> Coercing LHS to a list
> 5: In x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA) :
> Coercing LHS to a list
> 6: In x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA) :
> Coercing LHS to a list
> 7: In x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA) :
> Coercing LHS to a list
> 8: In x$State <- ifelse(data$State == "x", data$State, NA) :
> Coercing LHS to a list

Comment: Please include minimal & representative sample data (using either `dput` or through code that generates sample data). It's best to also include your expected output for some minimal sample data.

Comment: As for your `for` loop: You are overwriting `x`. In `for (x in States)` the value of `x` takes on values from `States`. You then set `x` equal to `data` in the next step (of which we don't know anything as you don't share `data`). This is probably not intended behaviour.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use `split(data, data$State)` to get a list of data sets?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidy solution using group_split():

```
data %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  group_split()
```